# Como atribuir a formula da célula D2 numa variável?

Tags: vba, excel-vba

CÓDIGO:

```
Range("AB2").Select
Dim tudo As String  
data_pasta = Format(Date, "/yy/mm/")

tudo = "https://pagina.pt/wp-content/imagens" & data_pasta & **D2** ".png"

ActiveCell.Value = tudo
ultima_linha = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Range("AB2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("AB2:AB" & ultima_linha)
```

EXEMPLO: `https://pagina.pt/wp-content/imagens/17/31/`**1234122**`.png`

Comment: você gostaria da formula em si ou do valor que ela resulta?

Acho valido você explicar um pouquinho melhor sua pergunta e explicar passo a passo o que está acontecendo e o que está em cada célula ou pelo menos passar o que está nas células que serão usadas na resposta. Do jeito que você escreveu fica muito abstrato, dando espaço para respostas que provavelmente não resolverão seu problema ou não funcionarão.

Comment: Pretendo passar o valor da célula A2 para dentro da variável tudo como demonstra no exemplo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para obter o valor da célula `A2` use `Range("A2").Value`. Pode substituir seu texto `** A2 **` por isso, mas não esqueça de colocar o `&` antes do `".png"`.

Comment: Gracias @PedroMVM!

Answer (score 0):

RESPOSTA: **.Value**

```
Range("AC2").Select
Dim tudo As String
data_pasta = Format(Date, "/yy/mm/")
tudo = "https://www.pagina.pt/wp-content/imagens" & data_pasta & Range("D2").Value & ".png"
ActiveCell.Value = tudo
Lastrow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Range("AC2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("AC2:AC" & Lastrow)
```